# No sound on any Linux distro

Tags: linux, audio

I seem to have no audio input or output, but Bluetooth headphones work. Interestingly, `pulseaudio` reports as though sound was being played when playing a YouTube video. This problem persists across distributions, and seems related to kernel drivers, as reverting to before kernel version 5.10 gives basic (bad) audio.

I've spent a long time trying to answer this question on my own. I can't remember all the different methods that I've tried. What I have done on a fresh boot of arch is install:

- `sof-firmware`
- `alsa-ucm-conf`

I have also tried a kernel module fix to no change:

```
options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=1
```

I've seen from similar posts that `inxi` is appreciated.

```
[username@hostname ~]$ inxi -A
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl
  API: ALSA v: k6.5.6-arch2-1 status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PulseAudio v: 16.1 status: active
```